# Compare and Update two DF using UDF

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have DF1:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+                                                               
|         source|            org|            val|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      [a,b,c,d]|              1|              1|
|      [e,f,g,h]|              2|              0|
|        [i,j,k]|              3|              1|
|        [u,v,z]|              4|              1|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

and DF2:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|         source|            org|
+---------------+---------------+
|              a|              1|
|              e|              7|
|              x|              3|
|              z|              4|
+---------------+---------------+
```

Now, I'd like to compare the `source[list]` from `DF1` to `source` from `DF2`. If the `source` from `DF2` is in the `source[list]` of `DF1`, the `val` and `org` part of both the dataframes are compared, and further the value of `new_val` in DF2 is to be set. This should be the logical representation of the process(I guess):

```
def spark_cassandra_connect():
        os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 pyspark-shell'
        os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3'
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkCassandraApp')\
                .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost')\
                .config("spark.driver.memory","4g")\
                .config("spark.executor.memory","4g")\
                .config("spark.driver.cores","4")\
                .config("spark.num.executors","6")\
                .config("spark.executor.cores","4")\
                .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042')\
                .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE')\
                .master('local[6]')\
                .getOrCreate()

        sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=spark.sparkContext, sparkSession=spark)
        return (sqlContext,spark.sparkContext)

func_udf = f.udf(org_check, IntegerType())
DF1 = sqlContext.read\                             
       .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
       .options(table="multi_source_data", keyspace="source")\
       .load()
DF1.withColumn('new_val', func_udf(DF1.source, DF1.org, DF1.val))



def org_check(source_list, org, val):
    if val == 0
        new_val = 0
    else:
        DF2 = sqlContext.read\                               #---> Problem Statement HERE
            .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
            .options(table="single_source_data", keyspace="source")\
            .load()

        for x in source_list:
            elements = DF2.filter(DF2.source.isin(x)).take(1)
            for element in elements:
                if(element.org == org):
                    new_val = 1
                else:
                    new_val = 2
    return new_val
```

And the resultant `DF1` looks like

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+                                                               
|         source|            org|            val|        new_val|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      [a,b,c,d]|              1|              1|              1|     #Since `a` is in DF2 and val is 1 and org matches
|      [e,f,g,h]|              2|              0|              0|     #Since `e` is in DF2 and val is 0
|        [i,j,k]|              3|              1|              0|     #Since `k` is in DF2 and val is 1 but org does not match
|        [u,v,z]|              4|              1|              1|     #Since `z` is in DF2 and val is 1 and org matches
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

But this requires me to load the `DF2` in the `UDF` itself, for it to load the DataFrame and process it further. This means that another `SQLContext` will get initialized unnecessarily everytime, and possibly for each row in `DF1`. Which seems pretty inefficient to me. Is it not possible to pass the `SQLContext` from the previous control statement to the `UDF` so that it does not init every time?

Further, since I'm new to PySpark, I couldn't really figure out other means to achieve the same in an efficient manner.

Any approach or help should suffice. Grateful already.

Comment: How large is the scond dataframe?  Consider to collect / broadcast it and analyze it in the UDF. Ottherwise: JOIN the dataframes and then apply regular SQL to perform your desired evaluation.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler The second dataframe has relatively more number of rows and columns than the first one. Also, collect/broadcast are something I've never worked with. Join, I think requires intersection of homogenous columns amongsts two df's and here, the type of columns to be co-related are different.

Comment: Firstly, do not load the second DF in the UDF - this is not recommended and extremely inefficient / an antipattern / will not properly work. I think you do have matching columns - but maybe have not fully realized: A) org and B) source seem to be shared among both. However, source is a list in one DF and for the other it is a scalar value. Assuming this assumption (you have shared columns) is correct you have two options:

Comment: 1) join on org and ISIN for source 2) using explode and potential reaggregation

Comment: @GeorgHeiler 1st suggestion wouldn't work since org needs to get validated if and only if source ISIN source['list']. Hence, the join will come possibly after the ISIN part.